# Trying to write a dplyr version of plyr::ldply

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, purrr

I could get the expected dataframe with the following code.

```
plyr::ldply(1:10, function(x){mean(sample(1:6, 2, replace = T))})
```

However can I reproduce the result using any dplyr version.
Not able to use `dplyr::do()` function as it does not accept class of numeric or integer variables.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `purrr` functions here instead of `dplyr` :

For example with `map_dbl` :

```
library(purrr)
data.frame(V1 = map_dbl(1:10, function(x){mean(sample(1:6, 2, replace = T))}))
```

Or with `map_df` :

```
map_df(1:10, function(x){data.frame(V1 = mean(sample(1:6, 2, replace = T)))})
```

---

The same can be done in base R with `sapply` :

```
data.frame(V1 = sapply(1:10, function(x){mean(sample(1:6, 2, replace = T))}))
```